# Exclude JS libs from org.owasp dependency-check-maven

Tags: maven, owasp

We use the following Maven Plugin to monitor our libraries that have security problems.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <suppressionFiles>
                    <suppressionFile>${project.basedir}/owasp-suppressions.xml</suppressionFile>
                </suppressionFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

At present, we only want to monitor our java libraries. There is a different team that is responsible for problems in the JS, which they monitor using a different process. My difficulty is that my Java-Lib monitoring aborts with errors every time that a JS problem is detected.

Is it possible to exclude the JS libs from the check entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that seems not to be possible.
Best solution I found was to use *scanSet* property to hard define the directories which should be analysed, and then off-course only defining those paths who contain java code.

```
<configuration>
   <scanSet>
      <fileSet>
         <directory>src</directory>
      </fileSet>
   </scanSet>
</configuration>
```

See https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/configuration.html for more info about 'scanSet' configuration.

Comment: The best that I was able to do was:  <fileSet<directory>${project.basedir}</directory><includes><include>pom.xml</include></includes></fileSet>

It seems to have done the trick, but it's not very satisfying...